# Leaflet Drag and drop to change existing markers

Tags: leaflet, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a project where the user should be able to drag an image to a pre-existing marker and have the marker update color if the value of the marker (a value w/in the geojson) and image (a value w/in the img attributes) are the same. I was thinking I'd use jQuery ui's drag and drop to handle the dragging, but I can't figure out how I'd isolate the specific marker as the droppable area and check the value of that marker.

When I inspect the markers in chrome, all I see is the div for marker pane, not any of the individual markers. So I'm lost as to how I'd access the markers w/ jQuery? Any ideas?

Basically, I'm trying to replicate [this functionality](http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/card-game.html), but with geojson generated markers instead of the card slots.